# Visual Basic .Net software behaves differently from machine to machine

Tags: vb.net, dll

I've inherited a lot of custom made software for an office, and, while managing it, I've found it performs differently from machine to machine.

I mean, some controls get painted in weird ways in some machines but well in another, or just work differently, like in some machines clicking something selects it, and in the next machine clicking the same thing makes it editable.

I suspect, of course, of the myriad of DLL the software loads.

Why does it happen? Is there any way of avoiding it?

Edit:

- All the machines are Windows XP SP3, Internet Explorer 8
- "get paint in weird ways" to me means things like a control being painted 300 or 400 pixels bigger in a machine than in the others (overlapping part of the GUI).

Comment: Not enough information. You first need to find out _why_ these differences occur.

Comment: That's part of the question, I'm editing it to clarify.

Comment: you still haven't given enough information to give you a solid answer.  We don't even know what controls you are using... custom or otherwise.  We don't know what your code does.  We don't know what "painted in weird ways" means to you.  Fill in the gaps.  Break it down issue by issue, and try again.

Comment: You haven't even specified whether all the different machines are running the same or different versions of Windows. There are definitely differences in the way WinXP paints some controls vs Vista or Win7, for instance. Also +1 to the COM reg answer below. Depending on what versions of various COM ActiveX dlls are registered on the different machines (and which DLL's your app uses) you could easily see differing results.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: it was caused by a combination of third party libraries and an absurd installation of the files needed for the software.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that some COM components are the issue (COMCTL32 would be my first guess), and that it isn't really a VB.NET problem. Versioning in the .NET world has been made so that the typical DLL hell issues shouldn't happen as they did before, but there are always some relics around...

Without more info I doubt that there will be a final answer to your question. You may want to start your troubleshooting by comparing Windows, Service Packs and IE versions.

Comment: Also process explorer will help you identify what DLL's are getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Ensure all machines have the exact same updates applied.  This goes beyond the service pack.  Run Windows Update on each machine and apply everything you can.  I suspect you have radically different patch levels across the board.

Step 2. Ensure all machines have the native screen resolution set.  This is more important for flat panels than the ancient CRT monitors.

Step 3. Look at the video drivers.  Make sure you have the latest ones for those machines.

Step 4. Make sure the exact same version of your app really is deployed across all of the machines.  If there are external dependencies, verify those are the same as well.